# Rails Active Record Relations to Enumerable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, enumerable

In certain cases when I get an ActiveRecord Relation I'm experiencing strange behavior with `.each` on an ActiveRecord::Relation

It seems to be when ActiveRecord::Relation delegates `:each` to `:to => :to_a` ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb))

```
@tasks = Task.find_task(list, {:week_id => 1})
```

Basically, there's a lengthy class method that takes an object (`list`, and a hash with a `:week_id`)

A bunch of filtering & queries happen within this `find_task` method, but it ends up returning a relation to `@tasks`

Then, in the template, I have:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
.
.
.
<% end %>
```

For whatever reason, no matter the size of `@tasks`, it takes ~3 minutes.  I Can replicate this same behavior by calling `@tasks.to_a`  Even if `@tasks`, an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation is only two records, calling `to_a` on them takes > 3 minutes.

It doesn't happen on all `:week_id`s, only on a specific week_id, for example: `:week_id => 1`

The SQL executes fine and I get a relation back, it just seems to be a problem with enumerable on a specific ActiveRecord::Relation.

***Update***

Inside the algorithm (I think this means the class method) I do a LOT of eager loading.  So Postgres does a lot of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s and I've indexed all the tables that this needs to happen on.

An explain analyze shows that all scans are `index scans` and as it turns out the query executes just fine with a lot of eager loading... and I get an eager loaded 'ActiveRecord::Relation` back in a reasonable amount of time.

***Update 2***
While this process is taking 3 minutes I see a postgres process run for a few seconds, and then I see this for 3 minutes as my output in `top`:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+    COMMAND                                                            
 8685 dylan     20   0 3407m 2.6g  904 R 99.7 69.1   1:14.49 /usr/local/bin/ruby script/rails s
```

When it finally finishes, The server shows this;

- eager loading: `200 ms`, `139 ms` then
- a big SQL Query with lots of `LEFT OUTER JOINS in 33,000 ms`, (long, but not where the majority is) then
- `257,000 ms` in the template.

And when I replicate the behavior in the template I see that it takes ~3-4 minutes to call `to_a` on the `@tasks` Relation.

So, when my server tells me all that time is spent in the template, and I can see calling an enumerable on the relation takes forever, is that when the query gets executed?  Even though in `top` I can only see the `ruby` process running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the eager loading.  When calling an enumerable method on an ActiveRecord::Relation instance it gets delegated to `.to_a`, which can take a really long time with a huge set of relations.  Even though I was looping through `@tasks`, I had eager loaded so many objects that `.to_a` was taking too long.

My short-term fix is to simply eager load fewer objects, even though it ends up hurting me with n+1 queries.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for future reference, this would be solved by using `find_each` instead.

You can find more info in the [Ruby on Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches).